# Getting handshake error 9806 while trying to connect to Meteor from iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, meteor, openssl

I am trying to use a library called ObjectiveDDP in my Swift app. I can connect to the sample app like this :

```
 var meteorClient = initialiseMeteor("pre2", "wss://ddptester.meteor.com/websocket");
```

When I am trying to connect to my local meteor server , I am getting this error : 
 CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)

I am running iOS 8.1 on Simulator. Any idea what I am missing ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite likely your local instance does not use SSL.

So protocols like `https` or `wss` will not be able to connect.

Try using `ws://` instead of `wss://`

Comment: Thanks @Akshat that did solve the issue. Although I am not getting the SSL handshake failure, but still I am not able to connect. Can you point me to a working example where a meteor-server is connected to an iOS client? I can post more code if you want to take a look.

Comment: @AbhishekMukherjee The examples with the iOS DDP client work. It may be a minor issue with your ip address, firewall or port being set incorrectly. It. See the examples: https://github.com/boundsj/ObjectiveDDP/tree/master/Example

Comment: Yes, after posting that comment , I was able to connect after making some modifications. Thank you for your help! Also, if I dont use NSFetchController, can I directly perform a data retrieval ? I am just starting with meteor and could use just a little hint on how to do the data fetch.

Comment: thank you so much for this. there's barely any info i can find if you are doing a Native iOS app and using meteor. Is there any other info you could point me in regarding this? I'm using the meteor-ios package here which seems cool https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios