# Connect meteor-ios to localhost

Tags: ios, swift, meteor

```
let Meteor = METCoreDataDDPClient(serverURL: NSURL(string: "wss://127.0.0.1:3000/")!)
```

or

```
let Meteor = METCoreDataDDPClient(serverURL: NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/")!)
```

Does not connect. How do I connect this to a localhost meteor instance?

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31198847/2227743

Comment: yep that was the one. Thank you.